# How can I edit the bounty message?

Tags: support, bounty

I had a [year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69845686/local-variable-result-might-be-referenced-before-assignment) which for a long time had only 1 answer that didn't sound correct, so I added a bounty with this message:

> The current answer does not make sense to me

But the answer I was referring to disappeared. The *current* current answer there is okay. Can I edit the bounty message so that it doesn't cause confusion?

It was a stupid message in hindsight. I didn't know that the current answer would disappear, and I should have anticipated that addition of new answers would make this bounty message ambiguous.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't. Bounty messages cannot be edited after being created. Mods (apparently) can't clear the bounty message without clearing the entire bounty notice, which includes the statement that there is a bounty.

Comment: Oh, that is sad. Everything else on the site seems to be editable. Could you please remove this bounty message for me?

Comment: Well, that was a bit excessive. That cleared the entire bounty notice. Could've sworn there was a way to just clear the message. The bounty is still in place though. I'm gonna ping a CM real quick and see if I can undo that

Comment: Yes thanks, I didn't want the entire dialog removed, just the custom message

Comment: Yeah, that was not what I wanted to do. Turns out that's not possible. CMs can't restore it without dev intervention. The CM recommended just clearing the bounty. Some testing indicates it shouldn't double the amount it's required to be, so I'll go ahead and do that. You'll have to make a new bounty. This isn't something we'd normally do (bounties are fundamentally non-refundable), but this is a bit of an excessive screw-up on my part, so...

Comment: As an aside, there's a [long-standing FR to edit bounty messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112188/332043). I've now cleared the bounty, so you can make a new one. On the bright side, you get a few extra days out of your rep

Comment: Ah, don't worry about it, I think that bounty had already served its purpose anyway. FR to edit has been sitting there for 11 years, probably no hope for that one

Comment: @nooboverflow you should add the bounty back, for fairness. The now-removed bounty helped you get more visibility for the question, and got you 3 recent answers.